# Mock useSelector with different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying something like this:

```
const useSelector = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useSelector,
}));
```

Then trying to do something like this:

```
useSelector.mockReturnValueOnce({});
shallow(
  <ComponentUsingUseSelector />
);
```

That will give me an error:

> The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.

So if I can't use an out of scope variable for a mock then how would I return a different value for every test?

Answer (score 6):

Simplified version, which also works:

```js
import * as redux from 'react-redux'

jest
  .spyOn(redux, 'useSelector')
  .mockReturnValueOnce('first call')
```

Also, instead of relying on multiple calls to `mockReturnValueOnce` it's better to just stub the necessary part of the store:

```js
const locale = 'en'

const state = {
  application: { locale },
}

jest
  .spyOn(redux, 'useSelector')
  .mockImplementation((callback) => callback(state))
```

Answer (score 5):

The following seems to work, after reading tons of articles and documentation that does not do what I (think) need to do; finally found one that does.

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useSelector: jest.fn(),
}));


describe('some test', () => {
  it('do something', () => {
    useSelector.mockImplementation(() => ('hello world'));
    shallow(
      <ComponentUsingUseSelector />
    );
```

If it's called multiple times I can do:

```
describe('some test', () => {
  it('do something', () => {
    useSelector.
      .mockReturnValueOnce('first call')
      .mockReturnValueOnce('second call')
    shallow(
      <ComponentUsingUseSelector />
    );
```

Comment: I think it could be useful to be clear about one thing:
It doesn't work if we try to implement values at the beggining, I mean, is a mandatory to init the mock with:

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useSelector: jest.fn(),
}));

Answer (score 1):

### Update answer to versions `react-redux` v8

> Cannot redefine property: useSelector issue

If you're getting the following error:

```
  TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useSelector
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
```

Apply this before tests:

```js
import * as Redux from 'react-redux';

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
    useSelector: jest.fn()
}));
```

Example:

```js
import * as Redux from 'react-redux';

// This will enable to mock readonly
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
    useSelector: jest.fn()
}));

describe('Component Tests', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.spyOn(Redux, 'useSelector').mockReturnValue({
            users: [] // your mock here
        });
       // or
       // (useSelector as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => ({
       //      useSelector:[] your mock
       // }));
    });
    test('should render component', () => {
        render(<MyComponent />);
    });
});
```